# How to add row elements in selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

[image]

I want to add today's count. I am new to selenium, and am not getting how to add using selenium. Can anyone suggest a solution?

This is my code:

```
package testpk;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;        
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;        
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.awt.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class Form {                


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {                                    

        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables        

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://beta-app.1bridge.in/#/auth/login"); 
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("RB0764",Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("kanna123",Keys.ENTER);

        Thread.sleep(7000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='dashboard']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pcoded\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/app-default/div/app-modal-basic/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p"));

        List listOfRows = (List) table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        System.out.println("Rows: "+listOfRows.size());

        //List<WebElement> listOfCols = listOfRows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td")); //If first row is normal row

        List<WebElement> listOfCols = ((WebDriver) listOfRows).get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th")); //If first row is header row

        System.out.println("Columns: "+listOfCols.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to help but first you need to learn good locators.  Using `WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pcoded\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/app-default/div/app-modal-basic/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p"));` will lead to problems.  Find a better shorter identifier and we'll see if that is the problem

Comment: See https://blog.mozilla.org/fxtesteng/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/ You are using ID's in some cases, which is good, but then having `div/div/div/div/div` makes them hard to read and brittle - any page layout change, no matter how unrelated, will break your automation which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can have the column value counts by using a 'for' loop (if that is what you are looking for).

```
       int intColValue=0;
       int sum=0;
       String strColValue;

       //Loop through all the rows
       for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
       {
           //Get the columns in particular row
           List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

           //Here I am assuming values are 'String' type
           //Also, I have hard-corded the column number (which you should not do and use column name as input) 
           strColValue = cols.get(2).getText();
           //And convert those to 'Integer'
           intColValue = Integer.parseInt(strColValue);

           //Get the sum
           sum = sum+intColValue;
       }

       System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
```

But as Michael mentioned, please use good locators.

Comment: I got ur point sir but  in that website id is not there i need complete code to add column count  could you please help me to do this

Comment: I haven't used 'id' anywhere in above code. So that should work as it is. Try once and let us know if you are facing any challenge.

Comment: Thank you sir but stil it showing 2 errors row cant be resolved

Comment: I have used 'rows' variable instead of 'listOfRows' variable that you have used. Just replace accordingly and try.